# Will Bouncy castle cause any security issue

Tags: java, security, ssl

I have an issue related to the `JDK1.6.0_45` version, where I am getting the below errors when I am run with `JBOSS 4.2.3.GA` and trying to connect to SQL server database :

1.Could not generate `DH Key Pair` at `com.sun.net.ssl.internal.ssl.Alerts.getSSLException`

2.`javax.net.ssl.SSLHandshakeException: java.security.cert. CertificateException`

3.Some issue regarding a server's public key being `2048 bit long` and `System` reporting the following:

> Prime size must be multiple of 64, and can only range from 512 to 1024

So for the solution I have used the `Bouncy Castle Provider` w/ the two below Jars and placed in our `jdk home ext` folder:

`bcprov-jdk15on-158.jar`

`ssl-provider-jvm16-0.2.jar`, and did changes in Java.security file by adding these provider

```
security.provider.2=net.tobszarny.ssl.java6.provider.BouncyCastleSSLProvider 
security.provider.3=org.bouncycastle.jce.provider.BouncyCastleProvider
```

after adding this the above issue was resolved, but for the security reasons I have a few questions and need your inputs:

Will Bouncy Castle Jar degrade the security since it is a third party library file?
Will it allow the TLS connection?
Will this cause any security issues or bypass the existing security?
Please share your suggestions.

Comment: JDK1.6.0_45 is far beyond end of live. And you are not only using BouncyCastle but you are using some derived work. I don't know whether the derived SSLProvider is branched from an actual version or not. In either way it's an additional risk.

Comment: To use 2048 bit keys by defalt you will need to install the `Unlimited Strength JCE Policy`. IMHO the current version of BC is much more secure than Java 6 (concerning security issues), thought even BC is using basic system calls. So if you really care about security, you rather upgrade the JRE..